# Download a Audio file using SessionManager in Alamofire 4 in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, ios10

In alomofire 3.5 the following code worked well

```
self.sessionManager.download(.GET, AppConstants.musicFileURL + musicFilename, destination: { (url, response) -> NSURL in
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        let fileUrl = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(musicFilename)
        return fileUrl
      })
    .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
      self.percentageDownloaded[exhibitId]![artworkId] = (Double(totalBytesRead) ,Double(totalBytesExpectedToRead))
      let meanPercentageDone = self.calculatePercentageDoneForExhibit(exhibitId, artworkArray: self.artworkArray)
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
      appDelegate.notifyDownloadProgress(meanPercentageDone)
    }
    .response { _, _, _, _ in

      NSLog("Completed downloading audio file,%@ , for artwork %@", musicFilename, artworkId)
      if DataManager.saveMusicDownloadComplete(artworkId, exhibitId: exhibitId){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.notifyMusicDownloadsComplete(exhibitId)
        self.percentageDownloaded[exhibitId] = [String: (Double, Double)?]()
        NSLog("when all music files have been downloaded")
      }
  }
}
```

How to migrate above code to Alamofire 4. Not able to see any comments in Migration document.

Comment: Try it: https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @JamshedAlam, the tutorial is for Swift 2.2. Sadly not for Swift 3

Comment: you can convert it to swift 3

Comment: @JamshedAlam, yes, i did

Answer (score 0):

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    documentsURL.appendPathComponent(musicFilename)
    return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
}

Alamofire.download(AppConstants.musicFileURL + musicFilename, to: destination)


    .downloadProgress { progress in
        print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }

    .responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
        print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")

    })
```

I changed with `Alamofire.download` instead for download in `SessionManager`

Comment: If I want to use SessionManager in order to have background capability, how can i make it work?

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#session-manager have a look